# Order attribute skips classes with multiple test fixtures

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I'm ordering some simple test classes by applying Order attribute.

```
namespace TestProject1
{
    [Order(2)]
    public class Class1
    {
       [Test]
        public void A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }
    }
    
    [Order(1)]
    public class Class2
    {
        [Test]
        public void B()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }
    }
    
    [Order(0)]
    public class Class3
    {
        [Test]
        public void C()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C");
        }
    }
}
```

And getting expected output:

```
C
B
A
```

Then I'm adding TestFixture attribute to one of the classes:

```
[TestFixture("1")]
[Order(1)]
public class Class2
{
    private string s;
    public Class2(string s)
    {
        this.s = s;
    }

    [Test]
    public void B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}
```

And still getting expected output:

```
C
B
A
```

But when I'm adding second TestFixture

```
[TestFixture("1")]
[TestFixture("2")]
[Order(1)]
public class Class2
{
    private string s;
    public Class2(string s)
    {
        this.s = s;
    }

    [Test]
    public void B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}
```

And I'm getting

```
C
A
B
B
```

instead of

```
C
B
B
A
```

Is this expected behavior and I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `OrderAttribute` is applied to fixtures, it orders them *within their containing test suite*, not globally. In your initial example, the containing suite is the one generated for the namespace. Since all the fixtures are in the same namespace, they run in the order you expected.

However, when you run multiple instances of the same fixture, an additional test suite is generated to contain those instances. That "invisible" suite does not have an `OrderAttribute` and, being invisible, there is no way for you to give it one. I'll call that one suite I in this discussion.

When the tests are run, the suites with an order attribute run first, followed by the one with no attribute:

1. C (order 1)
2. A (order 3)
3. I (unordered)

Since I contains the two B suites, they run last.

This behavior is really just the logical consequence of mixing parameterized and non-parameterized tests in your ordering logic. Of course, if you want it to work differently, you may feel it's a bug. :-)

UPDATE

@mozhirin asks "...shouldn't I be able to order this invisible suite?"

Perhaps you should. Thinking about it, I'm starting to see this as a bug, which someone might consider reporting to the developers!

You can't currently do it because NUnit interprets the `OrderAttribute` as applying to each individual fixture. But that serves no useful purpose, since each one gets the same ordering value, and it makes it impossible to effectively order fixtures when any of them use parameters. NUnit could just as easily apply the `OrderAttribute` to the invisible wrapping suite when multiple parameterized fixtures are involved.

Comment: Oh, I get it, but shouldn't I be able to order this "invisible" suite? It exists within initial suite, a single OrderAttribute can be added to it and OrderAttribute won't affect inner fixtures.

Comment: Yes, you've convinced me! See updated answer.

Comment: Already reported (:
https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/3868

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this integrates with your existing code's attributes but I found this looking through Microsoft's docs for ordering tests. These are at the method level rather than class, but I wasn't sure whether comma-separating the attributes would give you a different result for what you're looking for.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/order-unit-tests?pivots=nunit

Relevant bits:

```cs
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace NUnit.Project
{
    public class ByOrder
    {
        public static bool Test1Called;
        public static bool Test2ACalled;
        public static bool Test2BCalled;
        public static bool Test3Called;

        [Test, Order(5)]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Test3Called = true;

            Assert.IsTrue(Test1Called);
            Assert.IsFalse(Test2ACalled);
            Assert.IsTrue(Test2BCalled);
        }

        [Test, Order(0)]
        public void Test2B()
        {
            Test2BCalled = true;

            Assert.IsTrue(Test1Called);
            Assert.IsFalse(Test2ACalled);
            Assert.IsFalse(Test3Called);
        }
...
```

Also note your test runs may be multi-threaded, you could be fighting a race condition:

https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/order.html

> 5. Tests do not wait for prior tests to finish. If multiple threads are in use, a test may be started while some earlier tests are still being run.